# Approaches to cap/modify the terminal 3' OH of DNA polymer

Tags: organic-chemistry, biochemistry, alcohols

I am looking for a procedure that would cap/protect the 3' hydroxyl of DNA molecules with high efficiency. I have tried to perform a similar step enzymatically using dideoxynucelotide triphosphates but have found the efficiency to be unacceptable for my application, so I am exploring non-enzymatic approaches.

If this process also has side reactions that modify other hydroxyls (including 2' hydroxyls on RNA and/or other moieties on proteins), that would also be OK as long as the internals of the DNA backbone or the bases are not modified.

There is a standard part of some in-situ nucleic acid hybridization protocols that reacts tissue sections with acetic anhydride in a triethanolamine solution. The stated purpose of this step is to acetylate the 2' OH on RNA, and to acetylate some amino groups on proteins, and reduce background in subsequent hybridization steps.

1) Is there any reason to think that these conditions would NOT efficiently acetylate at the 3' hydroxyl of DNA (and RNA)?

2) Would this approach (acetic anhydride in basic conditions) cause any modifications to the standard DNA bases? I am specifically concerned that the primary amines critical for base pairing would be acetylated, which would be undesirable.

Comment: Hi Yashka, welcome to Chemistry.SE! We hope you enjoy your stay, please take the [tour] to familiarize yourself with the site!

Comment: Are you tring to protect only $\ce {3'-OH}$ and/or $\ce {2'-OH}$, but not $\ce {5'-OH}$, correct? I'm just tring to understand your need.

Comment: If there is an exposed 5' OH,  (for most biologically derived DNA there would be a phosphate there) it would not matter for my experiment if it was protected or not.

Comment: I understand that, but wasn't sure you want to cap $\ce{OH}$s after treat them with resricted enzymes.

Comment: Check this light sensitive protecting group (o-nitrobenzyl halide): _Proc. Natl. Acad. Sci. USA_, __1994__, _91_, 5022-5026 (May issue).

Comment: PDF available online: http://www.pnas.org/content/pnas/91/11/5022.full.pdf

Comment: I am not sure how this applies to my situation. I am looking for an irreversible/stable cap, and I’m starting with fully sysnthesized DNA , not being synthesized from 3’ to 5’ as Olivia, as in the paper.